# How to serve fonts from a service worker

Tags: javascript, fonts, service-worker, utf

I am attempting to serve fonts from a service worker. All of the fonts are ttf. The font files are base64 encoded on the server side, sent over http in JSON format, then stored in indexedDB as an array buffer.

I've verified that the encoded texts match in characters, and the decoded texts match in length. However, I'm getting a different "OTS parsing error" for each file. Could the data be getting corrupted somewhere?

I would like to avoid the Service Worker Cache API to keep support as wide as possible, however when I do use the Cache API the files load without error.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

**UPDATE**: After running a checksum on both decoded files, I can confirm there is some corruption.

**UPDATE**: Instead of base64, I saved the file as a byte array and ended up with the same errors. Now I'm suspecting a UTF propblem -- the question tags have been updated.

Comment: Seems like if Service Worker  is supported the cache would be too ...no?

Comment: MDN has it marked as [unsupported in IE and Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: No surprise with IE

Comment: What's the actual code you're using to convert the data from IDB into a `Response` object?